# What is the meaning of "crash out" in this context?

Tags: phrase-usage

I read a sentence in "The Hindu" which was:

A day earlier, a majority of the MPs decided to rule out, under all circumstances, Britain's crashing out of the EU without an agreement.

According to Cambridge dictionaries, "crash out" means either "falling asleep" or "losing". But that doesn't seem to fit here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine going to a car show room, getting in a car, then 'crashing out' of the showroom by driving through the display windows (rather than through the proper garage door)

Crash out in this instance means to leave something in an uncontrolled manner.

Comment: Nice and vivid example